# .yaml file syntax error when parsing cannot find issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, yaml, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to implement Amazon S3 active storage to add image upload capabilities to my web app and am currently trying to debug an issue i face when editing or creating a new product on the app itself and uploading an image to it.

```
RuntimeError in ProductsController#update
YAML syntax error occurred while parsing /Users/Sneha1/Desktop/sbhamra/streetwear_app/config/storage.yml. Please note that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not allowed. Error: (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 11 column 1
```

The line in question is as follows:

```
Use rails credentials:edit to set the AWS secrets (as aws:access_key_id|secret_access_key)
```

This line was default and simply uncommented and there are no odd spaces or indentation so i cannot determine the issue.

My products controller is as such for editing:

```
  def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product_id = @product.id 
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: "Product was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

File field on edit form is: `<%= f.file_field :image_url %>`

image_url is a resource on my product model and also in my params, but I cannot figure out why I'm getting the above issue when trying to upload any images.

Any help i can get would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's likely you uncommented a comment line instead of the line with a key/value, or the correct line. It'd be easier to diagnose if you posted some surrounding context.

Comment: whats at line no 11 of `storage.yml` file. Looks like line no 11 have missing `:`